# JSZIP execution stops if new tab is opened

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jszip

Using the following code I generate a new zip containg files.

```
let newZipFile = await compressAllDicoms(newDicoms);


async function compressAllDicoms(dicoms) {
let zip = new JSZip();
let i = 0;

eventBus.$emit('updateProgressText', "compressingDicoms");

dicoms.forEach((file) => {
    if (file) {
        zip.file(file.filename, file.content, {binary: true});
    }
});

return zip.generateAsync({type: "blob", streamFiles: true}, function updateCallback(metadata) {
    eventBus.$emit('updatePb', Math.ceil(metadata.percent));    
})
```

}

The following part :

```
return zip.generateAsync({type: "blob", streamFiles: true}, function updateCallback(metadata) {
    eventBus.$emit('updatePb', Math.ceil(metadata.percent));    
})
```

freezes if the user goes to another browser tab.

This was observed in FireFoxand Chrome only if the tab is within the same window.

Once the user returns to the tab, the progress continues.

If the user just defocusses the browser (e.g. by opening another program), but without changing the tab within the browser window, the progress continues. Also if the user opens another browser window without changing the tab in the browser window holding the  tab, the progress also continues.

What could be the issue here?